# Regex for individual characters between () but excluding what's ouside

Tags: regex, split, character

I need a regex that works as follows, I've been trying for a day and can't figure it out.

```
(IIILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;II)V = ['I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 
     'Ljava/lang/String;', 'Ljava/lang/String;', 'I', 'I'] Ignoring whats after )

(IIJ)J = ['I', 'I', 'J']   

(IBZS)Z = ['I', 'B', 'Z', 'S']
```

I've gotten `(I|D|F|Z|B|S|L.+?;)` so far but I can't get it to ignore that character that's after ')'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?<=\([^()]{0,10000})[A-Z][^A-Z()]*(?=[^()]*\))
```

- `(?<=\([^()]{0,10000})` Positive lookbehind ensuring what precedes is `(`, followed by any character except `(` or `)` between 0 and 10000 times. The upper limit may be adjusted as needed, but must not be infinite.
- `[A-Z]` Match any uppercase ASCII letter
- `[^A-Z()]*` Match any character except an uppercase ASCII letter, `(` or `)` any number of times
- `(?=[^()]*\))` Positive lookahead ensuring what follows is any character except `(` or `)` any number of times, followed by `)`

Results:

```
['I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'Ljava/lang/String;', 'Ljava/lang/String;', 'I', 'I']
['I', 'I', 'J']
['I', 'B', 'Z', 'S']
```

Sample code: [See in use here](https://ideone.com/Bfa7tY)